# message:ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource in oracle transaction

Tags: oracle, node-oracledb

I have below code for running transaction. I keep getting error like   `message:ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`. But if same is executed second time, it works fine. Does code seem buggy at any place?

```
async transactionData(postData) {
        var options = {
            autoCommit: false
        };
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                let transactionError = false;
            let connection = await this.getConnection();
                let transactionErrorMsg = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < postData.length; i++) {
                    const sql = postData[i].query;
                    const binds = postData[i].binds;

                    try {
                        await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
                    } catch (e) {
                        transactionErrorMsg = e.message;
                        transactionError = true;
                        console.log('Transaction error', transactionErrorMsg);
                        logger.error(transactionErrorMsg);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (transactionError) {
                    connection.rollback((err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            resolve({ "status": false, "message": err })
                        } else {
                            resolve({ "status": false, "message": `Transaction failed due to ${transactionErrorMsg}` })
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    connection.commit((err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            resolve({ "status": false, "message": err })
                        } else {
                            resolve({ "status": true, "message": 'Transaction passed' })
                        }
                    });
                }
                connection.release();
            } catch (e) {
                resolve({ "status": false, "message": e.message })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you the only user that is accessing the same table at that moment of time? Because, you can't *deadlock* yourself, you need someone else.

Comment: Yes i am the only user, i am sending 8-10 queries to execute in transaction. Does it matter?

Comment: It could, if those queries use separate sessions.

Comment: Ideally it uses same session, as i use only one connection, after all queries are execute, i release the connection.

Comment: Does it mean that those 8-10 queries are executed serially, one after another? If so, if that's the same transaction and same session, then no - I don't think that they can block each other.

Comment: yes those are executed one after the another

Comment: The mix of promises and async/await looks unnecessary and a possible source of errors.

Comment: @ChristopherJones - If i don't use promise how will i make requester wait until transactionData complete.

Comment: That's what await does for an async function: remove all the promise stuff and call 'await transactionData(x)' just like you do when you use await in, for example, the connection.execute() call

Comment: Not sure if my basics is wrong. if i do await transactionData, transactionData should return a promise right?